# What is the database password of a tenant's database (Laravel Hyn)

Tags: multi-tenant

I have deployed a multi-tenant site on the server and I'm using Laravel Hyn (5.6). I am able to create tenant's database. But I wonder what is the password used to create the tenant's database. I'm asking this because if ever we need to check on a tenant's database, how can we access it? And I'm trying to access it remotely. I can get into the app's main database which holds the tenant's database name. But I don't know how to access the tenant's actual database because I don't know what password Hyn assigned to it.

Checking Laravel Hyn's docs, It doesnt mention anything about it.

Answer (score 4):

The functionality you are looking for is in class Hyn\Tenancy\Generators\Database\DefaultPasswordGenerator function generate

Possibly if we can adapt this functionality to come up with a command that accepts the database name and returns the password. We can come up with something like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Models\Website;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Contracts\Website as WebContract;

class GeneratePassword extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'password:generate {--database=}';

    /** php artisan password:generate --database=6003c07826144979a4176b3290963ba3
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $database=$this->option('database');

        $website =Website::where('uuid', $database)->first();
        $password=$this->generate($website);
        $this->info('password :'.$password);

        return 0;
    }

     /**
     * @param Website $website
     * @return string
     */
    private function generate(WebContract $website) : string
    {
        $key = config('tenancy.key');

        // Backward compatibility
        if ($key === null) {
            return md5(sprintf(
                '%s.%d',
                $this->app['config']->get('app.key'),
                $website->id
            ));
        }

        return md5(sprintf(
            '%d.%s.%s.%s',
            $website->id,
            $website->uuid,
            $website->created_at,
            $key
        ));
    }
}
```

You will now be able to generate passwords via artisan console for example

```
 php artisan password:generate --database=6003c07826144979a4176b3290963ba3
```

Use the generated password to connect to your database using tenant credentials (username is the same as database name).

Comment: super solution thanks :)